# How to set good parameters clustering high density data with DBSCAN?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-science, dbscan

I want to cluster some stars based on given position (X,Y,Z) using DBSCAN, I do not know how to adjust the data to get the right numbers of clusters to plot it afterward?

this is how the data looks like
[image: enter link description here]
what is the right parameters for these data?

the number of rows are  1.202672e+06

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('datasets/full_dataset.csv')
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
clusters=DBSCAN(eps=0.5,min_samples=40,metric="euclidean",algorithm="auto")
```

Comment: Lol, why is your number of rows a double? And what is the "right" number of clusters? There is no right and wrong in clustering.

Answer (score 1):

min_samples is arguably one of the tougher ones to choose, but you can decide that by just looking at the results and deciding how much noise you are okay with.

Choosing eps can be aided by running k-NN to understand the density distribution of your data. I believe that the DBACAN paper recommends in more detail. There might even be a way to plot this in python (in R it is kNNdistplot).

I would prefer to use OPTICS, which is essentially doing all eps values simultaneously. However, I haven't found a decent implementation of this in either in python or R. In fact, there is an incorrect implementation in python which doesn't follow the original OPTICS paper at all.

If you really want to use optics, I recommend using a java implementation available using ELKI.

If anyone else has heard of a proper python implementation, I'd love to hear it.

If you want to go the trial and error route, start eps much smaller and go from there.